# How to make JScrollPane dynamically scroll to the end after adding components?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

Here is my code for the ScrollPane

```
    public class CustomScrollPane extends JScrollPane {

    private static CustomScrollPane instance = null;

    public CustomScrollPane () {
        super(panel.getInstance()); // a panel that the scrollpane wraps around
        this.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        // hide the vertical scroll bar
        this.getVerticalScrollBar().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0, 0));
    }

    public static CustomScrollPane getInstance() {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new CustomScrollPane ();
        return instance;
    }
```

I tried to do `getVerticalScrollbar.setValue(getVerticalScrollbar().getMaximum())` but it does not scroll to the end when I add JLabels to it. I'm trying to make it so that it will always scroll to the bottom of the screen once a new JLabel gets added to the panel. I din't use JTextArea as I want each line to have a different foreground color, so I used JLabels.

I also tried adding this method

```
public void scrollToBottom() { getVerticalScrollbar().getMaximum(); }
```

but it just freezes the ScrollPane and I am unable to scroll.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you hope to achieve by extending `JScrollPane`, not sure that it's really its core responsibility, after all, you could have its "viewport view" do it itself, for example...

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(-1, 8));
            for (int index = 0; index < 1000; index++) {
                contentPane.add(new SqaurePane());
            }
            add(new JScrollPane(contentPane));

            JButton top = new JButton("Top");
            JButton bottom = new JButton("Bottom");

            JPanel actionPane = new JPanel();
            actionPane.add(top);
            actionPane.add(bottom);

            add(actionPane, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

            top.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    contentPane.scrollRectToVisible(new Rectangle(0, 0, 1, 1));
                }
            });
            bottom.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    contentPane.scrollRectToVisible(new Rectangle(0, contentPane.getHeight(), 0, 0));
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }
    }

    static List<Color> COLORS = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Color[] {
        Color.BLACK,
        Color.BLUE,
        Color.CYAN,
        Color.DARK_GRAY,
        Color.GRAY,
        Color.GREEN,
        Color.LIGHT_GRAY,
        Color.MAGENTA,
        Color.ORANGE,
        Color.PINK,
        Color.RED,
        Color.WHITE,
        Color.YELLOW,
    }));

    public class SqaurePane extends JPanel {

        public SqaurePane() {
            Collections.shuffle(COLORS);
            setBackground(COLORS.get(0));
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(50, 50);
        }        
    }
}
```

The magic is right here...

```
top.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        contentPane.scrollRectToVisible(new Rectangle(0, 0, 1, 1));
    }
});
bottom.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        contentPane.scrollRectToVisible(new Rectangle(0, contentPane.getHeight(), 0, 0));
    }
});
```

Here, I'm asking the `contentPane` (which is the container holding all the squares) to "scroll to a visible rectangle" based on my needs

Now, in you case, when you add a new component to the "container", you would need to instruct the component to scroll to a position which would show the new component.

This is going to be a little more complicated as you will need to trigger a layout pass first, so you can get the new size of the container

## Dynamic addition to the container...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(-1, 8));
            add(new JScrollPane(contentPane));

            for (int index = 0; index < 8 * 8; index++) {
                contentPane.add(new SqaurePane());
            }

            Timer timer = new Timer(500, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    SqaurePane sqaurePane = new SqaurePane();
                    contentPane.add(sqaurePane);
                    contentPane.revalidate();
                    // There is an issue with how the layout pass runs, this 
                    // "seems" to be getting pushed onto the EDT later, which
                    // is messing up the scroll logic.
                    // So, instead, we push this on to the EDT to be executed
                    // "later" after the layout pass has run.  Yes, I tried
                    // calling doLayout directly, but, for the first element
                    // of each row, it wouldn't work correctly
                    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            contentPane.scrollRectToVisible(new Rectangle(0, sqaurePane.getY(), 1, sqaurePane.getHeight()));
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(400, 400);
        }
    }

    static List<Color> COLORS = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Color[]{
        Color.BLACK,
        Color.BLUE,
        Color.CYAN,
        Color.DARK_GRAY,
        Color.GRAY,
        Color.GREEN,
        Color.LIGHT_GRAY,
        Color.MAGENTA,
        Color.ORANGE,
        Color.PINK,
        Color.RED,
        Color.WHITE,
        Color.YELLOW,}));

    public class SqaurePane extends JPanel {

        public SqaurePane() {
            Collections.shuffle(COLORS);
            setBackground(COLORS.get(0));
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(50, 50);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, if you really wanted to decouple the concept, you could us a [`ContainerListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/containerlistener.html) and react to the new component been added via it

Comment: Thanks for the reply! my understanding is that I just have to add a short delay each time after adding a component so that the scrolling works?

Comment: @ell In context to the answer, yes.  The layout doesn't seem to be fully completed immediately after call `add` and `revalidate`, this seems to be API design, where part of the layout workflow is done "later" on the EDT, so we add a new `Runnable` AFTER it so we can get the full layout information correctly.  It should also point out that this only seemed to effect the first element of a new row